# Why does Linux need both "char_device_struct" and "cdev" structures to represent character devices?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I'm reading the code of Linux driver model. I know that when I want to register a range of character devices, I have to first use functions like `register_chrdev_region()` to register some `char_device_struct` stuctures to chrdevs[] hash chain, then use function like `cdev_add()` to register `cdev` stuctures into `cdev_map` hash chain. I found that the difference between the `char_device_struct` and `cdev` is that `char_device_struct` only includes device number information, but since `cdev` has both device number information and file operations information, why cannot just merge them into one structure?

Any answer will be good.

Comment: Because you can't know ahead the major:minor pair for you character device. It used to be in old kernels IIUC that the predefined numbers were used and there you can do that. In new, dynamic model that behaviour is deprecated. Btw, look at `old_*()` in kdev_t.h,